# How To Smoothly Animate From One Camera Position To Another

Tags: unity, animation, camera

The Question is basically self explanatory. I have a scene with many cameras and I'd like to smoothly switch from one to another. I am not looking for a cross fade effect but more to a camera moving and rotating the view in order to reach the next camera point of view and so on. To this end I have tried the following code:

```
    firstCamera.transform.position.x = Mathf.Lerp(firstCamera.transform.position.x, nextCamer.transform.position.x,Time.deltaTime*smooth);
    firstCamera.transform.position.y = Mathf.Lerp(firstCamera.transform.position.y, nextCamera.transform.position.y,Time.deltaTime*smooth);
    firstCamera.transform.position.z = Mathf.Lerp(firstCamera.transform.position.z, nextCamera.transform.position.z,Time.deltaTime*smooth);

    firstCamera.transform.rotation.x = Mathf.Lerp(firstCamera.transform.rotation.x, nextCamera.transform.rotation.x,Time.deltaTime*smooth);
    firstCamera.transform.rotation.z = Mathf.Lerp(firstCamera.transform.rotation.z, nextCamera.transform.rotation.z,Time.deltaTime*smooth);
    firstCamera.transform.rotation.y = Mathf.Lerp(firstCamera.transform.rotation.y, nextCamera.transform.rotation.y,Time.deltaTime*smooth);
```

But the result is actually not that good.

Thank you all, I fixed it this way

```
 var pos:Vector3 = firstCamera.transform.position;
    var rot:Quaternion = firstCamera.transform.rotation;
    firstCamera.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(pos, nextCamera.transform.position,Time.deltaTime*smooth);
    firstCamera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(rot, nextCamera.transform.rotation,Time.deltaTime*smooth);
```

Comment: in the first line is the `ply1.transform.position.x` a mistake and meant to be `nextCamera.transform.position.x`?

Comment: also, consider using a 3rd party tweening library like [iTween](http://itween.pixelplacement.com/index.php)

Comment: You are using `Lerp()` incorrectly; please see [this blog article](http://www.blueraja.com/blog/404/how-to-use-unity-3ds-linear-interpolation-vector3-lerp-correctly).

Comment: Using Lerp to perform an exponential ease-out blend like this is not incorrect per se — it cam often give a very pleasing feel for camera moves in particular. [We just need to ensure that we adjust for deltaTime correctly](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/149106/39518), as this is done wrong in almost every example out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using Quaternion.Lerp or [Quaternion.Slerp](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Slerp.html) instead of lerping the euler angles directly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the original position/rotation of `firstCamera`. It seems to be using the current values.

Comment: Using the current position as the start of a lerp and passing in a small value (i.e. delta time) is a cheap way of doing an ease-out.

Comment: That's true. I was trying to come up with a reason "the result is not that good".