# Add Lerp on only the Y axis

Tags: unity, camera, transformation, lerp

I want my camera to be smooth on only the Y axis.How do I do that it?

Current code:

```
public Transform target;
public float smoothSpeed = 0.3f;
public float offsetX = 1f;
public float offsetY = 1f;
public float offsetZ = 1f;


void FixedUpdate ()
{
    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    pos.x = target.position.x;
    pos.y = target.position.y;
    pos.z = target.position.z;
    Vector3 positionz = pos.z;

    Vector3 smoothedPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, pos, smoothSpeed);
    transform.position = smoothedPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just lerp only the y component.

Don't be afraid to just try stuff like this yourself — it's a lot faster to muck with a few formulas and see what they do than wait for an answer from a stranger. ;)

```
Vector3 pos = target.position;

pos.y = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.y, pos.y, sharpness);

transform.position = pos;
```

Note that to get consistent behaviour under varying framerates, you'll need to [adjust the sharpness parameter as explained here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/149106/39518).