# How can i make that when pressing F fast many time it will scale the object down/up smooth without waiting?

Tags: unity, c#

The first script is for the F pressing and calling the ScaleChange:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DroidMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject droid;
    public ChangeScale changeScale;

    private bool toDisplay = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        droid.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0, 0, 0); 
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            toDisplay = !toDisplay;
            changeScale.Scale(toDisplay);
        }
    }
}
```

The second script make the scaling:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeScale : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToScale;

    private float _currentScale = InitScale;
    private const float TargetScale = 0.7f;
    private const float InitScale = 0f;
    private const int FramesCount = 10;
    private const float AnimationTimeSeconds = 0.1f;
    private float _deltaTime = AnimationTimeSeconds / FramesCount;
    private float _dx = (TargetScale - InitScale) / FramesCount;

    private IEnumerator ScaleUp()
    {
        bool upscaling = true;
        while (upscaling)
        {
            _currentScale += _dx;
            if (_currentScale > TargetScale)
            {
                upscaling = false;
                _currentScale = TargetScale;
            }
            objectToScale.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * _currentScale;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(_deltaTime);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ScaleDown()
    {
        bool downscaling = true;
        while (downscaling)
        {
            _currentScale -= _dx;
            if (_currentScale < InitScale)
            {
                downscaling = false;
                _currentScale = InitScale;
            }
            objectToScale.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * _currentScale;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(_deltaTime);
        }
    }

    public void Scale(bool scaleUp)
    {
        if (scaleUp)
        {
            StartCoroutine(ScaleUp());
        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(ScaleDown());
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is if i press on F and it start scaling up and not finished yet the scaling and i press F again instead start scaling down it's like pausing and if i keep pressing F it will keep scaling up each time a bit.

What i want is if i press F and it start scaling to one direction up.down in the middle while it's scaling then change the scaling direction.

The variable TargetScale is like max scale and InitScale is like a min.
I want to keep it with the max and min but to make that if in the middle when it's scaling i press F change the scaling direction and not to pause it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to scale the object to `min` or `max`, when `F` is pressed.

Try this one out:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TestScaleScript : MonoBehaviour {

    private readonly Vector3 maxScale = Vector3.one * 5f;
    private readonly Vector3 minScale = Vector3.one;
    private Vector3 targetScale;
    private float scaleSpeed = 15f;

    private void Awake(){
        this.targetScale = maxScale;
    }

    private void Update(){
        this.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(this.transform.localScale, targetScale, Time.deltaTime * scaleSpeed);   

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            if(this.targetScale == maxScale) this.targetScale = minScale;
            else if(this.targetScale == minScale) this.targetScale = maxScale;
        } 
    }
}
```

Save it as `TestScaleScript.cs` in your scripts and attach it to any `GameObject` you want. Then, press `F` couple times.

Comment: Looks good. Just note that when using this style of Lerp, multiplying the blend factor by Time.deltaTime will not correctly adjust for variable framerate. [I show a time adjustment formula that works for this kind of exponential moving average in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/149106/39518).