# Lerp UI Color outside update method?

Tags: unity

I'm able to Lerp the color of a UI panel within the Update method. However I'd like to trigger behavior a single time when needed. If I put it in a method and call it it only changes for a brief time and doesn't fully complete. I could probably set a bool flag within the update method but that seems sloppy.

Comment: A tweener like [DoTween](http://dotween.demigiant.com) or a coroutine will work. Have you tried either?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Coroutine gives the desired effect.

```
IEnumerator ChangeColorTest()
    {
        for (var i = lerpDuration; i >= 0; i -= 0.1f)
        {
            UIPanel.color = Color.Lerp(startColor, endColor, Time.time / lerpDuration);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }
    }
```

I'd like the color transition to be smoother but this might be how Coroutines work.

Comment: "this might be how Coroutines work" nope. You're waiting a tenth of a second (ie. 3-6 frames) between iterations instead of updating the colour every frame (which you can do with `yield return null`). You're also [using the wrong calculation of the blend parameter to adjust for time](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/149103/why-use-time-deltatime-in-lerping-functions).