# How to make a concisely, elegantly, and human-friendly Quaternion camera?

Tags: opengl, camera, quaternion, glm

I have spent three weeks struggling with the quaternion camera!

Now I have two Implementations. **One has some kind of gimbal lock issue or something like that. Another one is totally anti-human** ( I feel like I am using a ZBrush camera to play a game).

**the faulty one:**

[image]

**the zbrush and anti-human one:**
[image]

**key codes of that two cameras:**

**the faulty one:**

```
void MouseInput(GLfloat xOffset, GLfloat yOffset, bool constrainPitch = 0) {
        xOffset *= turnSpeed;
        yOffset *= turnSpeed;

        if (glm::abs(glm::fmod(pitch, 360.0f)) < 90.0f || glm::abs(glm::fmod(pitch, 360.0f)) > 270.0f)
            yaw += xOffset;
        else
            yaw -= xOffset;

        pitch += yOffset;

        if (constrainPitch) 
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

```
void Update() {

        glm::quat qPitch = glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(-pitch), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0, 0));
        glm::quat qYaw = glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(-yaw), glm::vec3(0, 1.0f, 0));
        glm::quat qRoll = glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(roll), glm::vec3(0, 0, -1.0f));

        orientation = glm::normalize(qYaw * qPitch * qRoll);

        front = glm::normalize(orientation * glm::vec3(0, 0, -1.0f));
        up = glm::normalize(orientation * glm::vec3(0, 1.0f, 0));
        right = glm::normalize(orientation * glm::vec3(1.0f, 0, 0));

        fps = ViewMatrix();
        tps = ViewMatrixOrbital();
    }
```

**the zbrush and anti-human one:**

```
void MouseInput(GLfloat xOffset, GLfloat yOffset) {
        xOffset *= turnSpeed;
        yOffset *= turnSpeed;
        
        yaw = xOffset;
        pitch = yOffset;
    }
```

```
void Update() {
        glm::quat qYaw = glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(-yaw), up);
        glm::quat qPitch = glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(-pitch), right);
        glm::quat qRoll = glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(roll), front);

        orientation = glm::normalize(qRoll * qPitch * qYaw * orientation);

        front = glm::normalize(orientation * glm::vec3(0, 0, -1.0f));
        up = glm::normalize(orientation * glm::vec3(0, 1.0f, 0));
        right = glm::normalize(orientation * glm::vec3(1.0f, 0, 0));

        fps = ViewMatrix();
        tps = ViewMatrixOrbital();

                //Clear Everything
        yaw = 0;
        pitch = 0;
        roll = 0;
    }
```

**The view matrix functions of both of them are the same:**

```
    glm::mat4 ViewMatrix() {
        glm::mat4 translate = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), position);
        glm::mat4 rotate = glm::mat4_cast(orientation);
        return glm::inverse(translate * rotate);
    }

    glm::mat4 ViewMatrixOrbital() {
        glm::mat4 translate = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), localPosition);
        glm::mat4 aroundOnePoint = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), aroundPoint);
        glm::mat4 rotate = glm::mat4_cast(orientation);
        return glm::inverse(aroundOnePoint * rotate * translate);
    }
```

The first one is messed up when I **look directly from up to down** or **down to up**.

The second one, I can never go back to the **same position** when I just drag/draw a circle with my mouse...

I really need some help to make a human-friendly, "robust", and elegantly quaternion camera(some things like the camera in the Ace Combat or EVERSPACE)...

> The resources I have used:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609654/quaternion-based-first-person-view-camera
>
> http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-17-quaternions/
>
> https://www.3dgep.com/understanding-the-view-matrix/
>
> and of course...
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d4EgbgTm0Bg&ab_channel=3Blue1Brown

Sorry for my English...

Comment: What you call a "zbrush" camera is working correctly. If this is not what you want, perhaps you don't need quaternions at all? Does your game world have a fixed "up" direction?

Comment: I hope that my game world does not have a fixed "up" direction. 

I want something like a jet or plane flying upside down or a spaceship that can rotate to any direction. 

I hope the camera can be human-friendly/intuitively( only "roll" when I want to "roll", my "zbrush camera" rolling all the time...).

Comment: Then you somehow need to artificially correct this roll, which isn't straightforward. Consider what happens when you rotate the camera 90 degrees up, then left, then down. This adds up to a 90 deg CCW roll, and is completely normal. You're observing the same effect on a smaller scale.

Comment: OK, I think I understand why my camera is anti-human now...

...And any tips about how to "remove" those kinds of rolls?  google keyword? links resource? some pages of some books? someone's GitHub?

Comment: Nope, don't know how to do that. If this was my game,  I'd probably leave it as it is.

Comment: It's not clear to me from reading this question how you *want* your camera to behave. Can you make an edit to describe what behaviour you'd like to see for a series of different rotation scenarios? If you want help [smoothly neutralizing an unwanted roll that's accumulated, see this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/175306/39518), or to [understand why that roll creeps in at all, see this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/136175/39518).

Comment: Thank you DMGregory!!!! I think I just made something blow my mind!!!!!!!!!!
I will post an "answer code" soon, and I will extremely welcome everyone to improve it!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, thanks for the links from DMGregory and the ideal form HolyBlackCat.

I think that I find a temporary solution.

Of course, it is not very elegant and not perfect...
Any suggestions or comments are very welcome！

**new Update() function**

```
void Update(float delta) {
        
        glm::quat qYaw = glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(-yaw), up);
        glm::quat qPitch = glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(-pitch), right);
        glm::quat qRoll = glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(roll), front);
```

```
        orientation = glm::normalize(tempQuat * qRoll * qPitch * qYaw * orientation);
```

Here I add a **tempQuat** which is used for correcting the "roll".

```
        front = glm::normalize(orientation * glm::vec3(0, 0, -1.0f));
        up = glm::normalize(orientation * glm::vec3(0, 1.0f, 0));
        right = glm::normalize(orientation * glm::vec3(1.0f, 0, 0));
```

```
        auto ClosestAxis = [](glm::vec3 v) {...};
```

**ClosestAxis** is a helper function that is used to find the closest axis(like (0,1,0), actually I add all the axes and all the vectors between those axes).

```
        glm::vec3 UpNormal = glm::normalize(glm::cross(front, ClosestAxis(up)));
        glm::vec3 targetUp = glm::normalize(glm::cross(UpNormal, glm::cross(up, UpNormal)));
        if (!roll) 
        {
            glm::quat q = glm::rotation(up, targetUp);
            tempQuat = glm::slerp(glm::identity<glm::quat>(), q, delta * 2.0f);
        }
```

The first cross-product gets **a normal fo a plane**, the "human-friendly intuitive vertical plane".

The Next double cross-product comes from the ideal: [How can you make a projection of a vector onto a plane?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-make-a-projection-of-a-vector-onto-a-plane/answer/Sayan-Banerjee-1?ch=10&oid=247728993&share=0731c5c7&srid=hTpzFg&target_type=answer).
It projects the **up** to the "human-friendly intuitive vertical plane".

Now we can get a rotation quaternion between **up** and **targetUp**(the projected one), and we slerp them. I arbitrarily give a speed (**delta*2.0f**) of "correcting roll".

Because Update() will be executed every frame(actually, this function does something like infinitely close to targetUp), **it can be anything smaller than 1.0**(it may feel uncomfortable without a delta-time, like a plain number 0.01f ).

Other codes remain the same.

```
        fps = ViewMatrix();
        tps = ViewMatrixOrbital();

                //Clear Everything
        yaw = 0;
        pitch = 0;
        roll = 0;
    }
```

**the ClosestAxis lambda helping function**

```
auto ClosestAxis = [](glm::vec3 v) {
            auto axis = std::max
            (
                { 
                  glm::normalize(glm::vec3(1.0f,1.0f,0)),glm::normalize(glm::vec3(1.0f,-1.0f,0)),
                  glm::normalize(glm::vec3(-1.0f,1.0f,0)),glm::normalize(glm::vec3(-1.0f,-1.0f,0)),
                  glm::normalize(glm::vec3(1.0f,0,1.0f)),glm::normalize(glm::vec3(1.0f,0,-1.0f)),
                  glm::normalize(glm::vec3(-1.0f,0,1.0f)),glm::normalize(glm::vec3(-1.0f,0,-1.0f)),
                  glm::normalize(glm::vec3(0,1.0f,1.0f)),glm::normalize(glm::vec3(0,1.0f,-1.0f)),
                  glm::normalize(glm::vec3(0,-1.0f,1.0f)),glm::normalize(glm::vec3(0,-1.0f,-1.0f)),
                  glm::vec3{0, 0, 1.0f},glm::vec3{0, 0, -1.0f},
                  glm::vec3{1.0f, 0, 0},glm::vec3{-1.0f, 0, 0},
                  glm::vec3{0,1.0f, 0},glm::vec3{0, -1.0f, 0},
                  glm::normalize(glm::vec3(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f)),glm::normalize(glm::vec3(-1.0f,1.0f,1.0f)),
                  glm::normalize(glm::vec3(1.0f,1.0f,-1.0f)),glm::normalize(glm::vec3(-1.0f,1.0f,-1.0f)),
                  glm::normalize(glm::vec3(1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f)),glm::normalize(glm::vec3(-1.0f,-1.0f,1.0f)),
                  glm::normalize(glm::vec3(1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f)),glm::normalize(glm::vec3(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f)),
                },
                [&](glm::vec3 v1, glm::vec3 v2) {return glm::dot(v, v1) < glm::dot(v, v2); }
            );
            return axis;
        };
```

[image]