# Starting a Coroutine after another Coroutine ends

Tags: unity, c#, color, unity-ui

I have a method that fades the screen to black, then fades away back again using coroutines but I couldn't get the 2nd part to work.

`FadeToBlack()` works if I put `yield return null` instead of `yield return StartCoroutine(LightUp());` so I know that isn't the problem

```
 private IEnumerator FadeToBlack()
{
    
    for (float t = 0.01f; t < fadeOutTime; t += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        
        color = new Color(0, 0, 0, 1);
        night.color = Color.Lerp(night.color, color, Mathf.Min(1, t / fadeOutTime));            
        yield return StartCoroutine(LightUp());
        
    }}
```

If I put yield return `StartCoroutine(LightUp());` in FadeToBlack instead of null it immediately turns black without the fading part. Here's what `LightUp();` looks like

```
private IEnumerator LightUp() {
    for (float t = 0.01f; t < fadeOutTime; t += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        color = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);
      Color colorD = new Color(0, 0, 0, 1);
        night.color = Color.Lerp(colorD, color, Mathf.Min(1, t / fadeOutTime));


        yield return null;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to start your fade back to light coroutine *after* your fade to black loop has finished *all* of its work, not once in every iteration of the loop (ie. every frame the black fade is supposed to be updating).

Move it outside the loop like so:

```
private IEnumerator FadeToBlack()
{
    Color originalColor = night.color;

    for (float t = 0.01f; t < fadeOutTime; t += Time.deltaTime)
    {            
        night.color = Color.Lerp(originalColor, Color.black, t / fadeOutTime);            
        yield return null;        
    }

    yield return StartCoroutine(LightUp());
}
```

I also corrected your lerp, [which included a common error that makes the time adjustment incorrect](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/149106/39518).

We can even combine FadeToBlack and LightUp into one to remove the redundant code, then just call the coroutine twice:

```
public class FadeTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image night;
    public float fadeOutTime = 1f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(FadeThroughBlack());
    }


    private IEnumerator FadeThroughBlack() {
        yield return FadeTo(Color.black);
        yield return FadeTo(Color.clear);
    }

    private IEnumerator FadeTo(Color destination) {
        Color originalColor = night.color;

        for (float t = 0.01f; t < fadeOutTime; t += Time.deltaTime) {            
            night.color = Color.Lerp(originalColor, destination, t / fadeOutTime);
            yield return null;
        }

        night.color = destination;
    }
}
```

I've tested this and verified that it correctly fades the image to black, then fades it to transparent. If you don't observe this then you should edit your question to include a minimal complete verifiable example of the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you for taking an extra step to point out my other mistakes. Unfortunately it still doesn't proceed to the next coroutine. It just stays black. Also making the `originalColor` variable as a reference to `night.color` seems to just make it not work altogether

Comment: Have you fixed your second coroutine following the model of the first?

Comment: Yes, I did fixed it.

Comment: Thank you. The combined code works. Will keep in mind to avoid redundant code from now on